# How to increment integer and return new value?

Tags: sql

I would like to have a table that stores sequences for objects that have too many types for each of them to have a dedicated table with their own auto incrementing primary key. Is there a way to have a **single query** increment the sequence by one and return the resulting number while also ensuring the sequence exists?

The table would be simple:

```
+------------------------------+
| name(varchar)  |  value(int) |
|------------------------------|
| foo            |  1          |
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: If you want a sequence per type, and for each new row for a specific type you want a new value from that "type specific sequence", you could use just one sequence and then use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY seq) AS tseq` to get that "type specific sequence".  Is that your basic request?